# How to define multiplication of Natural Numbers in Haskell commutatively?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I was trying to define natural number multiplication in Haskell, and kept getting the error below (corresponds to the second natMult definition below).

```
Prelude> natMult (S (S Z)) (S (S Z))
*** Exception: <interactive>:(4,5)-(5,45): Non-exhaustive patterns in function natPlus
```

Here's my code:

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat deriving (Show)

natPlus :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
natPlus Z a = a
natPlus (S a) (S b) = natPlus a (S (S b))
```

After a bit of tinkering, I realized this definition works fine, whereas the second one below is broken.  The only difference is the order of the input parameters for natPlus.

```
-- works fine
natMult :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
natMult Z a = Z
natMult (S a) b = natPlus (natMult a b) b

-- gives gives the error above
natMult :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
natMult Z a = Z
natMult (S a) b = natPlus b (natMult a b)
```

Can anyone explain why this error arises?

---Edit---
The below definition is complete and solves the problem.  Thanks for the suggestions

```
natPlus Z a = a
natPlus (S a) b = natPlus a (S b)
```

Comment: Your definition of `natPlus` looks a bit buggy - have you tried computing eg. `natPlus (S Z) Z`?

Comment: You forgot the `natPlus (S a) Z` case.

Comment: I strongly recommend to turn on warnings, which would help you sport the issue immediately.

Answer (score 5):

In case of the `Non-exhaustive patterns in function natPlus` error, it is useful to **compile with the [`-Wincomplete-patterns`](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/flags.html#ghc-flag--Wincomplete-patterns) flag**. If we compile the program with this flag we obtain:

```
$ ghci -Wincomplete-patterns 
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> data Nat = Z | S Nat deriving (Show)
Prelude> :{
Prelude| natPlus :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
Prelude| natPlus Z a = a
Prelude| natPlus (S a) (S b) = natPlus a (S (S b))
Prelude| :}

<interactive>:4:1: warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘natPlus’: Patterns not matched: (S _) Z
```

So the compiler warns us that for `natPlus`, the case `natPlus (S _) Z` is *not* covered. Since this is an exercise, I suggest that you define this case. So your code should look like:

```
natPlus :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
natPlus Z a = a
natPlus (S a) (S b) = natPlus a (S (S b))
natPlus (S a) Z = -- ... your code here ...
```

Note that you can solve this by implementing a more generic pattern (for example `natPlus a Z`, You can try to define it in two clauses, for example `natPlus Z a = -- ...`, and `natPlus (S a) b = -- ...`